# How do I convert nested JSON into Go code?

Tags: go

I have used:

https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

to convert

```
{
    "id": 5533,
    "action": "/api/v1/private/subscribe",  
    "arguments": {
        "instrument": ["BTC-19DEC14"],
       "event": ["order_book", "trade", "user_order"]
    }
}
```

into

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    ID        int    `json:"id"`
    Action    string `json:"action"`
    Arguments struct {
        Instrument []string `json:"instrument"`
        Event      []string `json:"event"`
    } `json:"arguments"`
}
```

I have then tried to use this in Go code as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "os"
)

var addr = flag.String("addr", "www.deribit.com", "http service address")

func main() {

    type AutoGenerated struct {
        ID        int    `json:"id"`
        Action    string `json:"action"`
        Arguments struct {
            Instrument []string `json:"instrument"`
            Event      []string `json:"event"`
        } `json:"arguments"`
    }

    json := &AutoGenerated{
        ID:     42,
        Action: "/api/v1/public/getorderbook",
        Arguments: struct {
            Instrument: ["BTC-19DEC14"],
            Event:       ["order_book", "trade", "user_order"],
        },
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error with `Arguments` ie my struct within a struct.

How do I convert my JSON to a variable that I can use within go?

Answer (score 1):

example is ..

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

var addr = flag.String("addr", "www.deribit.com", "http service address")

type Arguments struct {
    Instrument []string `json:"instrument"`
    Event      []string `json:"event"`
}

type AutoGenerated struct {
    ID       int       `json:"id"`
    Action   string    `json:"action"`
    Argument Arguments `json:"arguments"`
}

func main() {

    json := &AutoGenerated{
        ID:     42,
        Action: "/api/v1/public/getorderbook",
        Argument: Arguments{
            Instrument: []string{"BTC-19DEC14"},
            Event:      []string{"order_book", "trade", "user_order"},
        },
    }

    fmt.Println(json)
}
```